# Style first character of second paragraph with css

Tags: html, css

```html
 <div class="ex1">
      <div>
        <p></p>
        <p>Exmaple 1</p>
        <p>Exmaple 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i can't select first character in "Exmaple 1" with css and i finding solution

Thanks for support

Comment: What do you mean by first character? The letter **"E"** ?

Comment: After reading your question , the answer, your comments to the answer. I suggest you start off by researching a little bit about CSS selectors. You said : ' i can't find a solution ' ( something like that ) . You can find a solution just by searching : ' style first letter css ' and then ' select second element css ' etc. Invest more in your own development, ask here only after you have tried ( really tried ) to find a solution by yourself

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about styling the first letter, then use `:first-letter` pseudo-element

```css
.ex1 p:first-letter{
  color:red;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div>
    <p>Example 1</p>
    <p>Example 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to only apply it in the first `p` then also use `:first-of-type`

```css
.ex1 p:first-of-type:first-letter{
  color:red;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div>
    <p>Example 1</p>
    <p>Example 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Finally, if you just want to target the second element then use `:nth-child(2)` or the second `p` then `:nth-of-type(2)`

```css
.ex1 p:nth-child(2):first-letter{
  color:red;
}
.ex1 p:nth-of-type(2):first-letter{
    font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div>
    <p></p>
    <p>Example 1</p>
    <p>Example 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer but if i have 2 tags p it will styling both . i only want frist tag p styling.

Comment: @GiangTran simply add a class to your first tag `p`

Comment: @GiangTran so, first character or first paragraph, or first character of first paragraph ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli yes exacly

Comment: @GiangTran updated answer